# Best practice to check that a component is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

Let's assume that a component returns null in render method, based on some prop.

What is the best way to use expect in order to ensure that component is not rendered?

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import Pagination from '../Pagination';

it('should not render if totaPages is 0', () => {
  const { container } = render(<Pagination activePage={1} totalPages={0} />);
  expect(container.firstChild).toBeNull();
});
```

Is the above code enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) you can do `expect(container).toBeEmptyDOMElement()`. I find it a bit more readable, but your solution works too

Comment: `Warning: toBeEmpty has been deprecated and will be removed in future updates. Please use instead toBeEmptyDOMElement for finding empty nodes in the DOM.`